# Java JPA GenerationType.Auto value always null

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have several classes in the same project in which the id is always autogenerated. However in this specific case the value of my id happens to be always null. I'm really wondering what is wrong, because after some changes it stopped working. And comparing it with the other classes the code seems to be the same.

```
package com.checkin.model.entity;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
public class Checkin {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String date;

public Checkin(){

}

public Checkin(String date){
    this.date = date;
    System.out.println(this.id);
    System.out.println(this.getId());
}


public Long getId() {return id;}

public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}

public String getDate() {return date;}

public void setDate(String date) {this.date = date;}

}
```

This is the repository where the objects are saved:

```
package com.checkin.model.repository;

import com.checkin.model.entity.Checkin;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository("checkinRepository")
public interface CheckinRepository extends CrudRepository<Checkin, Long> {
   Checkin findById(Long id);


}
```

and finally this is the result that I get from Postman

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwHWs.png)

Comment: whats the underlying database? and show the DDL definition of id column

Comment: I'm not exacly sure what you mean by DDL definition. I'm using Hibernate with JPA. And regarding your question about the underlying database, here's what I've used in my build.gradle:    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")

Comment: @AntonioDelaTorre Setup Hibernate to recreate database tables (and lost information) and enable the SQL log. You will have `DDL` in the log (SQL `CREATE TABLE` statements). Other way to generate DDL: https://geowarin.github.io/generate-ddl-with-hibernate.html. It is a bit more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Generation type `AUTO` sets the the underlying database to generate the ID
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html#AUTO

In this case, what you want to check is if the H2 database id column has the attribute to generate IDs. I am guessing it does not. I dont use AUTO much myself so I am assuming if your Auto works for other `Entities` then those are setup correctly.

You may need to do one of the following:

- migration here
- update column in H2
- recreate the table

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm following this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ But I don't think the problem is of h2 or with something from the JPA. Because, when I create and object and save it into the database in the manner stated inside the Application.java, by using:  public CommandLineRunner demo(CheckinRepository repository) {
  return (args) -> {
   // save a couple of customers
   repository.save(new Checkin("Jack"));   I get: 2017-05-29 16:50:09.035  INFO 33570 --- [           main] com.checkin.Application                  : Checkin: [id=1, Date='Jack']

Comment: So I think it has something to do with the RESTful interface

Comment: Thank you very much!! I solved the problem... It was one of the dumbest things you could imagine... I commented the .save in the database and naturally if the database doesn't receive the object it doesn't generate an ID...

Comment: glad you got it sorted out. And thanks for marking the answer correct even though you had a different problem. Please can you post the problem and the specific changes you did and mark your own answer as correct? I think it be quite beneficial to others. Or at least having a second possible solution would go a long way to investigate. thanks